# perfect coin is tossed n times. Let Sn denotes the number of heads obtained. What is the expectation of Sn?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

The Problem is: A perfect coin is tossed n times. Let Sn denotes the number of heads obtained. What is the expectation of Sn?

---

I got to E of $S_n$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \space\space\space Sn (\frac{1}{2})^n$

Comment: Wouldnt the expected value of $S_n$ just be $\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: $S_n$ has binomial distribution, parameter $1/2$. Standard result, the mean is $n/2$. For proof of result, let $X_i=1$ if we get head on the $i$-th toss, and $0$ otherwise. Then $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, and by the linearity of expectation $E(S_n)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_n)$.  Or we can do it the unpleasant way by manipulating $\sum_0^n n\binom{n}{k}(1/2)^n$.

Comment: "Sn" means "$S \times n$". To get the subscript use `$S_n$`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have $Sn$ (or $S_n$) inside the summation: $S_n$ is a random variable, but the left-hand side $\mathbb E(S_n)$ is not.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say a coin is tossed once: we get the Expectation of number of heads as

E[R] = no.of heads*prob(no.of heads) = 1*1/2 = 1/2.

Now let n=2, E[R2] = 2*1/4 + 1*2/4 + 0*1/4 = 1.

Now let n=3, E[R3] = 3*1/8 + 2*3/8 + 1*3/8 = 12/8 = 3/2.

As we keep continuing this we observe that E[Rn] = n*1/2.

This is the linearity of Expectation. That is, E[R] = E[R1] + E[R2] + .. . + E[Rn].